# Is it possible to detect where the join fails on a certain record?

Tags: sql

Please bear with me as this may be a question without a possible answer, but I hope I describe it correctly..

I have a query which joins a number of tables and produces results, and here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
  dbo.Property.PropertyPK, 
  dbo.Tenancy.TenancyPK, 
  dbo.Tenant.ContactFK, 
  dbo.Contacts.strTitle, 
  dbo.Contacts.strFirstName, 
  dbo.Contacts.strSurname 
FROM dbo.Property 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tenancy ON dbo.Property.PropertyPK = dbo.Tenancy.PropertyFK 
INNER JOIN dbo.Tenant ON dbo.Tenancy.TenancyPK = dbo.Tenant.TenancyFK 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Tenant.ContactFK = dbo.Contacts.ContactPK
```

The main table is the Property table and I filter out one row by specifying a PropertyPK in my criteria..

My question is..  If the Tenant or Contact record does not exist and I run my query in SQL Management Studio of course I get a message saying there are no rows but can I determine at what stage the join has failed between two tables?

I can of course check this in management studio but I am trying to help the user on the application side to inform them of why there are no rows.  My application is in VB and I will write that check if there are no rows and I cannot determine it in SQL..

Sorry for the question in advance..

Derek.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.PropertyPK, ty.TenancyPK, t.ContactFK,
       c.strTitle, c.strFirstName, c.strSurname
FROM dbo.Property p LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Tenancy ty
     ON p.PropertyPK = ty.PropertyFK LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Tenant t
     ON ty.TenancyPK = t.TenancyFK LEFT JOIN
     dbo.Contacts c
     ON t.ContactFK = c.ContactPK;
```

This will keep all rows in the `Property` table.  You can then see which primary keys are `NULL` to see if there were matches in the other tables.

Note that the query is much easier to write and to read when you use table aliases.

Comment: What a great answer, thank you..  I sort of thought of that but had in my mind that Left Joins will give me more results thank I want but I think I can deal with that easily..  Thank you!!  and yes the aliases would help.  Next time :)